# Hardware errors and mcelog

Tags: linux

Is mcelog a daemon, a cron job, or what? How do I force a check? What other ways are there to scan for hardware errors on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the mcelog [website](http://www.mcelog.org/) lays it out for you:

> The mcelog daemon accounts memory and some other errors errors in
>   various ways. `mcelog --client` can be used to query a running daemon.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to decode an mcelog log file on SLES 11 SP2:

```
sudo mcelog --dmi --ascii < /var/log/mcelog
```

Keep this in mind per the [mcelog man](http://www.mcelog.org/manpage.html) page:

> With the −−dmi option mcelog will look up the addresses reported in machine checks in the SMBIOS/DMI tables of the BIOS. This can sometimes tell you which DIMM or memory controller has developed a problem. More often the information reported by the BIOS is either subtly or obviously wrong or useless. This option requires that mcelog has read access to /dev/mem (normally requires root) and runs on the same machine in the same hardware configuration as when the machine check event happened.